# How can i get the last child of my example (CSS)?

Tags: css, sass

I am currently trying to get the last child element of a custom Button component (react) to change the margin-left to auto (align last item to the right).
I have a wrapping div Container which contains 3 of the custom Button elements.
They look like this:

[image: example css code]

Important:

1. I only have access to the `ActionButtonContainer` where i want to access the last custom Button div `class="button_ButtonContainer__vP7S- button_Confirm__36TCt"`
2. CSS Only
3. Helpful explanation would be nice.

How can i solve this?

i tried this and many more not working solutions:

```
 div.Button:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: none of your divs have a class of `.Button`

Comment: Yes i see your point. I tried way to many things since it didnt work out. So i came out with something like this and else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
._ActionButtonContainer_58606 > div:last-of-type {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Or, you can increase specificity:

```
._ActionButtonContainer_58606 > div[class^="button_ButtonContainer__vP7S"]:last-of-type {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both examples are working like a charm, updated my example with your solution.